# How to manipulate an attribute of an object in sql (oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, user-defined-types

Supposing i have this hierarchy :

```
create or replace type tperson as object(
    fname varchar2(20),
    lname tprenom,
    adress tadr,
    phone_num varchar2(10),
    email varchar2(50)
)not final;

create or replace type tuser under tperson(
    username varchar2(20),
    password varchar2(20)
);

create table agent(
id_ag int,
infos tuser not null
);

insert into agent values(1,tuser('name',tprenom('bilel','dani','lastname3')  
,tadr(3,'ain delfa','miliana','hammama',20), 
'2140547854','email@gmail.com','username','password'));
```

How could i **select, update** only a single attribute from agent table ?

I've tried that sql but it didn't work :

```
select infos.fname, infos.lname, infos.adress, infos.phone_num, infos.email, 
infos.username, infos.password from agent where id_ag=1;
```

But i'm getting this error :

> invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

What am i missing ?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: remove the semicolon after agent

Comment: Side notes: emails are allowed to be ~250 characters.  Phone numbers are up to 15 digits.  The common format for hashed passwords is (usually) going to end up way longer than 20 characters, which makes me think your passwords aren't hashed.  I'm a little surprised you don't have types declared for `fname` (especially since `lname` does...), `phone_num`, `email`, `username`, or `password`.

Comment: Yeah, i've forgot to mention these but it wasen't the problem you know. I can't beleive how easy was the solution that i wish i didn't ask the question lol. That's just for a home work but thanks for the advices though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon before the `where` that should not be there.

When it comes to accessing the user-defined column, use a table prefix and you should be fine.

Here is the syntax for your `SELECT` query :

```
select 
    ag.infos.fname,
    ag.infos.lname,
    ag.infos.adress, 
    ag.infos.phone_num, 
    ag.infos.email, 
    ag.infos.username, 
    ag.infos.password 
from agent ag
where ag.id_ag = 1;
```

If you are looking to perform an `UPDATE` :

```
update agent ag
set ag.infos.fname = 'foo', ag.infos.lname = 'bar'
where ag.infos.id_ag = 1
```